# How to extract an SVG file which is embedded in (FileMaker) XML as Hex Codes using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, string, xslt, entity

I have an XML file (a FileMaker fm14 layout fmxmlsnippet) which contains an SVG file in a HexData tag, like this:

```
<HexData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exData>
```

(The rest of the surrounding XML is unimportant)

I need to decode the SVG file out of the HexData

In other languages, this could be solved pretty much with one loop:

1. Convert each pair of hex-digits to a character...
2. ...concatenating this into a string as you go
3. output the string as an XML file

The loop is easily implemented in XSLT 1.0 as a recursive named template which reads off each two hex digits - but there it ends: XSLT 1.0 lacks a char() function!

My first character conversion solution - simply converting the hex characters into hex entities - is kind of half-successful...

The following named template:

```
<xsl:template name="HexData.toString">
    <xsl:param name="HexData"/>
    <!-- -->
    <xsl:if test="string-length($HexData)&gt;1">
        <!-- Output char as hex entity -->
        <xsl:value-of select="'&amp;#x'" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring($HexData,1,2),'abcdef','ABCDEF')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="';'"/>
        <!-- recurse -->
        <xsl:call-template name="HexData.toString">
            <xsl:with-param name="HexData" select="substring($HexData,3)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

...*nearly* produces the correct result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
&#x3C;&#x73;&#x76;&#x67;&#x20;&#x78;&#x6D;&#x6C;&#x6E;&#x73;&#x3D;&#x22;&#x68;&#x74;&#x74;&#x70;&#x3A;&#x2F;&#x2F;&#x77;&#x77;&#x77;&#x2E;&#x77;&#x33;&#x2E;&#x6F;&#x72;&#x67;&#x2F;&#x32;&#x30;&#x30;&#x30;&#x2F;&#x73;&#x76;&#x67;&#x22;&#x20;&#x78;&#x6D;&#x6C;&#x6E;&#x73;&#x3A;&#x78;&#x6C;&#x69;&#x6E;&#x6B;&#x3D;&#x22;&#x68;&#x74;&#x74;&#x70;&#x3A;&#x2F;&#x2F;&#x77;&#x77;&#x77;&#x2E;&#x77;&#x33;&#x2E;&#x6F;&#x72;&#x67;&#x2F;&#x31;&#x39;&#x39;&#x39;&#x2F;&#x78;&#x6C;&#x69;&#x6E;&#x6B;&#x22;&#x20;&#x78;&#x6D;&#x6C;&#x3A;&#x73;&#x70;&#x61;&#x63;&#x65;&#x3D;&#x22;&#x70;&#x72;&#x65;&#x73;&#x65;&#x72;&#x76;&#x65;&#x22;&#x20;&#x77;&#x69;&#x64;&#x74;&#x68;&#x3D;&#x22;&#x31;&#x30;&#x30;&#x70;&#x78;&#x22;&#x20;&#x68;&#x65;&#x69;&#x67;&#x68;&#x74;&#x3D;&#x22;&#x34;&#x36;&#x70;&#x78;&#x22;&#x20;&#x73;&#x74;&#x79;&#x6C;&#x65;&#x3D;&#x22;&#x73;&#x68;&#x61;&#x70;&#x65;&#x2D;&#x72;&#x65;&#x6E;&#x64;&#x65;&#x72;&#x69;&#x6E;&#x67;&#x3A;&#x67;&#x65;&#x6F;&#x6D;&#x65;&#x74;&#x72;&#x69;&#x63;&#x50;&#x72;&#x65;&#x63;&#x69;&#x73;&#x69;&#x6F;&#x6E;&#x3B;&#x20;&#x74;&#x65;&#x78;&#x74;&#x2D;&#x72;&#x65;&#x6E;&#x64;&#x65;&#x72;&#x69;&#x6E;&#x67;&#x3A;&#x67;&#x65;&#x6F;&#x6D;&#x65;&#x74;&#x72;&#x69;&#x63;&#x50;&#x72;&#x65;&#x63;&#x69;&#x73;&#x69;&#x6F;&#x6E;&#x3B;&#x20;&#x69;&#x6D;&#x61;&#x67;&#x65;&#x2D;&#x72;&#x65;&#x6E;&#x64;&#x65;&#x72;&#x69;&#x6E;&#x67;&#x3A;&#x6F;&#x70;&#x74;&#x69;&#x6D;&#x69;&#x7A;&#x65;&#x51;&#x75;&#x61;&#x6C;&#x69;&#x74;&#x79;&#x3B;&#x20;&#x66;&#x69;&#x6C;&#x6C;&#x2D;&#x72;&#x75;&#x6C;&#x65;&#x3A;&#x65;&#x76;&#x65;&#x6E;&#x6F;&#x64;&#x64;&#x3B;&#x20;&#x63;&#x6C;&#x69;&#x70;&#x2D;&#x72;&#x75;&#x6C;&#x65;&#x3A;&#x65;&#x76;&#x65;&#x6E;&#x6F;&#x64;&#x64;&#x22;&#x20;&#x76;&#x69;&#x65;&#x77;&#x42;&#x6F;&#x78;&#x3D;&#x22;&#x30;&#x20;&#x30;&#x20;&#x38;&#x2E;&#x38;&#x39;&#x31;&#x34;&#x35;&#x20;&#x34;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x35;&#x36;&#x35;&#x39;&#x22;&#x3E;&#x0D;&#x0A;&#x3C;&#x67;&#x20;&#x63;&#x6C;&#x61;&#x73;&#x73;&#x3D;&#x22;&#x66;&#x6D;&#x5F;&#x66;&#x69;&#x6C;&#x6C;&#x22;&#x3E;&#x0A;&#x20;&#x3C;&#x64;&#x65;&#x66;&#x73;&#x3E;&#x0A;&#x20;&#x20;&#x3C;&#x73;&#x74;&#x79;&#x6C;&#x65;&#x20;&#x74;&#x79;&#x70;&#x65;&#x3D;&#x22;&#x74;&#x65;&#x78;&#x74;&#x2F;&#x63;&#x73;&#x73;&#x22;&#x3E;&#x0A;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x0A;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x2E;&#x66;&#x69;&#x6C;&#x30;&#x20;&#x7B;&#x66;&#x69;&#x6C;&#x6C;&#x3A;&#x23;&#x30;&#x41;&#x30;&#x42;&#x30;&#x43;&#x7D;&#x0A;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x0A;&#x20;&#x20;&#x3C;&#x2F;&#x73;&#x74;&#x79;&#x6C;&#x65;&#x3E;&#x0A;&#x20;&#x3C;&#x2F;&#x64;&#x65;&#x66;&#x73;&#x3E;&#x0A;&#x20;&#x3C;&#x67;&#x20;&#x69;&#x64;&#x3D;&#x22;&#x4C;&#x61;&#x79;&#x65;&#x72;&#x5F;&#x78;&#x30;&#x30;&#x32;&#x30;&#x5F;&#x31;&#x22;&#x3E;&#x0A;&#x20;&#x20;&#x3C;&#x6D;&#x65;&#x74;&#x61;&#x64;&#x61;&#x74;&#x61;&#x20;&#x69;&#x64;&#x3D;&#x22;&#x43;&#x6F;&#x72;&#x65;&#x6C;&#x43;&#x6F;&#x72;&#x70;&#x49;&#x44;&#x5F;&#x30;&#x43;&#x6F;&#x72;&#x65;&#x6C;&#x2D;&#x4C;&#x61;&#x79;&#x65;&#x72;&#x22;&#x2F;&#x3E;&#x0A;&#x20;&#x20;&#x3C;&#x70;&#x61;&#x74;&#x68;&#x20;&#x63;&#x6C;&#x61;&#x73;&#x73;&#x3D;&#x22;&#x66;&#x69;&#x6C;&#x30;&#x22;&#x20;&#x64;&#x3D;&#x22;&#x4D;&#x35;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x34;&#x32;&#x34;&#x38;&#x20;&#x31;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x30;&#x32;&#x32;&#x33;&#x63;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x39;&#x30;&#x39;&#x31;&#x32;&#x37;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x35;&#x37;&#x30;&#x33;&#x31;&#x36;&#x20;&#x32;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x35;&#x38;&#x35;&#x36;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x39;&#x39;&#x34;&#x36;&#x35;&#x35;&#x20;&#x33;&#x2E;&#x33;&#x37;&#x32;&#x36;&#x38;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x37;&#x39;&#x35;&#x37;&#x34;&#x38;&#x20;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x34;&#x35;&#x38;&#x31;&#x34;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x33;&#x36;&#x30;&#x37;&#x34;&#x35;&#x20;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x37;&#x30;&#x37;&#x32;&#x34;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x35;&#x38;&#x34;&#x34;&#x33;&#x34;&#x20;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x31;&#x38;&#x30;&#x32;&#x38;&#x34;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x34;&#x32;&#x35;&#x37;&#x35;&#x32;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x39;&#x36;&#x39;&#x36;&#x39;&#x37;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x36;&#x38;&#x32;&#x39;&#x36;&#x36;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x31;&#x2E;&#x38;&#x39;&#x32;&#x33;&#x37;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x31;&#x36;&#x36;&#x35;&#x30;&#x38;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x32;&#x2E;&#x37;&#x31;&#x31;&#x35;&#x33;&#x2C;&#x31;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x36;&#x38;&#x32;&#x33;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x35;&#x34;&#x33;&#x33;&#x32;&#x36;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x36;&#x38;&#x31;&#x39;&#x37;&#x32;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x39;&#x33;&#x31;&#x39;&#x39;&#x39;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x31;&#x31;&#x32;&#x36;&#x35;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x31;&#x32;&#x36;&#x36;&#x32;&#x35;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x31;&#x34;&#x37;&#x32;&#x36;&#x38;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x32;&#x31;&#x33;&#x32;&#x30;&#x32;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x33;&#x32;&#x37;&#x38;&#x32;&#x38;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x34;&#x35;&#x31;&#x34;&#x37;&#x33;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x36;&#x30;&#x39;&#x36;&#x36;&#x39;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x37;&#x31;&#x34;&#x38;&#x31;&#x32;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x38;&#x34;&#x35;&#x35;&#x7A;&#x6D;&#x2D;&#x34;&#x2E;&#x38;&#x36;&#x39;&#x32;&#x38;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x37;&#x37;&#x30;&#x32;&#x33;&#x38;&#x63;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x31;&#x39;&#x31;&#x36;&#x32;&#x31;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x33;&#x32;&#x32;&#x33;&#x38;&#x36;&#x20;&#x32;&#x2E;&#x31;&#x37;&#x38;&#x35;&#x36;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x32;&#x39;&#x36;&#x32;&#x35;&#x37;&#x20;&#x32;&#x2E;&#x33;&#x31;&#x37;&#x39;&#x33;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x20;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x31;&#x37;&#x31;&#x31;&#x38;&#x38;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x35;&#x31;&#x35;&#x35;&#x33;&#x20;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x31;&#x38;&#x31;&#x36;&#x39;&#x37;&#x2C;&#x31;&#x2E;&#x31;&#x38;&#x31;&#x30;&#x37;&#x20;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x31;&#x30;&#x32;&#x30;&#x39;&#x37;&#x2C;&#x31;&#x2E;&#x39;&#x33;&#x30;&#x37;&#x33;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x31;&#x39;&#x35;&#x38;&#x32;&#x37;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x33;&#x32;&#x35;&#x30;&#x37;&#x39;&#x20;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x32;&#x30;&#x39;&#x30;&#x34;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x33;&#x33;&#x32;&#x34;&#x38;&#x36;&#x20;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x36;&#x30;&#x37;&#x34;&#x39;&#x34;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x31;&#x32;&#x32;&#x35;&#x35;&#x32;&#x20;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x31;&#x37;&#x32;&#x37;&#x37;&#x38;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x38;&#x36;&#x34;&#x36;&#x36;&#x33;&#x20;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x36;&#x31;&#x32;&#x39;&#x36;&#x39;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x33;&#x35;&#x34;&#x33;&#x33;&#x32;&#x20;&#x31;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x37;&#x36;&#x35;&#x37;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x37;&#x33;&#x31;&#x39;&#x35;&#x36;&#x20;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x31;&#x38;&#x31;&#x32;&#x32;&#x33;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x31;&#x34;&#x37;&#x36;&#x31;&#x20;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x33;&#x37;&#x37;&#x36;&#x33;&#x35;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x32;&#x39;&#x35;&#x32;&#x35;&#x33;&#x20;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x35;&#x38;&#x38;&#x31;&#x38;&#x37;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x34;&#x33;&#x36;&#x32;&#x39;&#x34;&#x20;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x32;&#x37;&#x36;&#x32;&#x32;&#x32;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x32;&#x37;&#x30;&#x32;&#x37;&#x32;&#x20;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x35;&#x31;&#x37;&#x35;&#x33;&#x39;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x35;&#x36;&#x35;&#x38;&#x31;&#x32;&#x20;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x37;&#x31;&#x38;&#x34;&#x34;&#x34;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x38;&#x39;&#x30;&#x36;&#x35;&#x39;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x38;&#x39;&#x38;&#x39;&#x39;&#x33;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x38;&#x34;&#x33;&#x36;&#x38;&#x39;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x32;&#x31;&#x36;&#x39;&#x31;&#x31;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x32;&#x33;&#x36;&#x33;&#x39;&#x34;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x35;&#x30;&#x30;&#x34;&#x32;&#x39;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x35;&#x34;&#x32;&#x37;&#x38;&#x35;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x36;&#x36;&#x34;&#x34;&#x38;&#x37;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x37;&#x31;&#x38;&#x30;&#x39;&#x31;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x32;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x35;&#x33;&#x37;&#x2C;&#x31;&#x2E;&#x35;&#x35;&#x33;&#x39;&#x39;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x33;&#x2E;&#x31;&#x34;&#x32;&#x30;&#x35;&#x2C;&#x31;&#x2E;&#x35;&#x30;&#x34;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x38;&#x30;&#x31;&#x30;&#x35;&#x38;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x33;&#x36;&#x37;&#x39;&#x32;&#x31;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x31;&#x2E;&#x35;&#x30;&#x38;&#x35;&#x35;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x32;&#x37;&#x33;&#x39;&#x38;&#x31;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x31;&#x2E;&#x37;&#x36;&#x38;&#x32;&#x35;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x31;&#x2E;&#x33;&#x33;&#x37;&#x33;&#x33;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x32;&#x36;&#x37;&#x36;&#x36;&#x37;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x31;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x39;&#x35;&#x39;&#x36;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x31;&#x39;&#x31;&#x32;&#x33;&#x35;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x31;&#x2E;&#x39;&#x31;&#x31;&#x37;&#x35;&#x20;&#x30;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x32;&#x2E;&#x34;&#x38;&#x35;&#x31;&#x35;&#x7A;&#x6D;&#x31;&#x2E;&#x31;&#x36;&#x39;&#x31;&#x31;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x31;&#x32;&#x32;&#x38;&#x33;&#x39;&#x63;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x34;&#x32;&#x38;&#x37;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x20;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x37;&#x37;&#x36;&#x33;&#x35;&#x33;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x33;&#x35;&#x30;&#x39;&#x32;&#x31;&#x20;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x37;&#x37;&#x36;&#x33;&#x35;&#x33;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x37;&#x38;&#x33;&#x37;&#x34;&#x39;&#x20;&#x30;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x34;&#x33;&#x32;&#x38;&#x32;&#x38;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x33;&#x34;&#x37;&#x36;&#x35;&#x33;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x37;&#x38;&#x33;&#x37;&#x34;&#x39;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x37;&#x37;&#x36;&#x33;&#x35;&#x33;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x37;&#x38;&#x33;&#x37;&#x34;&#x39;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x34;&#x32;&#x38;&#x36;&#x38;&#x39;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x37;&#x37;&#x36;&#x33;&#x34;&#x32;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x33;&#x35;&#x30;&#x39;&#x32;&#x31;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x37;&#x37;&#x36;&#x33;&#x34;&#x32;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x37;&#x38;&#x33;&#x37;&#x34;&#x39;&#x20;&#x30;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x34;&#x33;&#x32;&#x38;&#x32;&#x38;&#x20;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x33;&#x34;&#x37;&#x36;&#x35;&#x33;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x37;&#x38;&#x33;&#x37;&#x34;&#x39;&#x20;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x37;&#x37;&#x36;&#x33;&#x34;&#x32;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x37;&#x38;&#x33;&#x37;&#x34;&#x39;&#x7A;&#x22;&#x2F;&#x3E;&#x0A;&#x20;&#x3C;&#x2F;&#x67;&#x3E;&#x0A;&#x3C;&#x2F;&#x67;&#x3E;&#x0D;&#x0A;&#x3C;&#x2F;&#x73;&#x76;&#x67;&#x3E;&#x3C;&#x73;&#x76;&#x67;&#x20;&#x78;&#x6D;&#x6C;&#x6E;&#x73;&#x3D;&#x22;&#x68;&#x74;&#x74;&#x70;&#x3A;&#x2F;&#x2F;&#x77;&#x77;&#x77;&#x2E;&#x77;&#x33;&#x2E;&#x6F;&#x72;&#x67;&#x2F;&#x32;&#x30;&#x30;&#x30;&#x2F;&#x73;&#x76;&#x67;&#x22;&#x20;&#x78;&#x6D;&#x6C;&#x6E;&#x73;&#x3A;&#x78;&#x6C;&#x69;&#x6E;&#x6B;&#x3D;&#x22;&#x68;&#x74;&#x74;&#x70;&#x3A;&#x2F;&#x2F;&#x77;&#x77;&#x77;&#x2E;&#x77;&#x33;&#x2E;&#x6F;&#x72;&#x67;&#x2F;&#x31;&#x39;&#x39;&#x39;&#x2F;&#x78;&#x6C;&#x69;&#x6E;&#x6B;&#x22;&#x20;&#x78;&#x6D;&#x6C;&#x3A;&#x73;&#x70;&#x61;&#x63;&#x65;&#x3D;&#x22;&#x70;&#x72;&#x65;&#x73;&#x65;&#x72;&#x76;&#x65;&#x22;&#x20;&#x77;&#x69;&#x64;&#x74;&#x68;&#x3D;&#x22;&#x31;&#x30;&#x30;&#x70;&#x78;&#x22;&#x20;&#x68;&#x65;&#x69;&#x67;&#x68;&#x74;&#x3D;&#x22;&#x34;&#x36;&#x70;&#x78;&#x22;&#x20;&#x73;&#x74;&#x79;&#x6C;&#x65;&#x3D;&#x22;&#x73;&#x68;&#x61;&#x70;&#x65;&#x2D;&#x72;&#x65;&#x6E;&#x64;&#x65;&#x72;&#x69;&#x6E;&#x67;&#x3A;&#x67;&#x65;&#x6F;&#x6D;&#x65;&#x74;&#x72;&#x69;&#x63;&#x50;&#x72;&#x65;&#x63;&#x69;&#x73;&#x69;&#x6F;&#x6E;&#x3B;&#x20;&#x74;&#x65;&#x78;&#x74;&#x2D;&#x72;&#x65;&#x6E;&#x64;&#x65;&#x72;&#x69;&#x6E;&#x67;&#x3A;&#x67;&#x65;&#x6F;&#x6D;&#x65;&#x74;&#x72;&#x69;&#x63;&#x50;&#x72;&#x65;&#x63;&#x69;&#x73;&#x69;&#x6F;&#x6E;&#x3B;&#x20;&#x69;&#x6D;&#x61;&#x67;&#x65;&#x2D;&#x72;&#x65;&#x6E;&#x64;&#x65;&#x72;&#x69;&#x6E;&#x67;&#x3A;&#x6F;&#x70;&#x74;&#x69;&#x6D;&#x69;&#x7A;&#x65;&#x51;&#x75;&#x61;&#x6C;&#x69;&#x74;&#x79;&#x3B;&#x20;&#x66;&#x69;&#x6C;&#x6C;&#x2D;&#x72;&#x75;&#x6C;&#x65;&#x3A;&#x65;&#x76;&#x65;&#x6E;&#x6F;&#x64;&#x64;&#x3B;&#x20;&#x63;&#x6C;&#x69;&#x70;&#x2D;&#x72;&#x75;&#x6C;&#x65;&#x3A;&#x65;&#x76;&#x65;&#x6E;&#x6F;&#x64;&#x64;&#x22;&#x20;&#x76;&#x69;&#x65;&#x77;&#x42;&#x6F;&#x78;&#x3D;&#x22;&#x30;&#x20;&#x30;&#x20;&#x38;&#x2E;&#x38;&#x39;&#x31;&#x34;&#x35;&#x20;&#x34;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x35;&#x36;&#x35;&#x39;&#x22;&#x3E;&#x0D;&#x0A;&#x3C;&#x67;&#x20;&#x63;&#x6C;&#x61;&#x73;&#x73;&#x3D;&#x22;&#x66;&#x6D;&#x5F;&#x66;&#x69;&#x6C;&#x6C;&#x22;&#x3E;&#x0A;&#x20;&#x3C;&#x64;&#x65;&#x66;&#x73;&#x3E;&#x0A;&#x20;&#x20;&#x3C;&#x73;&#x74;&#x79;&#x6C;&#x65;&#x20;&#x74;&#x79;&#x70;&#x65;&#x3D;&#x22;&#x74;&#x65;&#x78;&#x74;&#x2F;&#x63;&#x73;&#x73;&#x22;&#x3E;&#x0A;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x0A;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x2E;&#x66;&#x69;&#x6C;&#x30;&#x20;&#x7B;&#x66;&#x69;&#x6C;&#x6C;&#x3A;&#x23;&#x30;&#x41;&#x30;&#x42;&#x30;&#x43;&#x7D;&#x0A;&#x20;&#x20;&#x20;&#x0A;&#x20;&#x20;&#x3C;&#x2F;&#x73;&#x74;&#x79;&#x6C;&#x65;&#x3E;&#x0A;&#x20;&#x3C;&#x2F;&#x64;&#x65;&#x66;&#x73;&#x3E;&#x0A;&#x20;&#x3C;&#x67;&#x20;&#x69;&#x64;&#x3D;&#x22;&#x4C;&#x61;&#x79;&#x65;&#x72;&#x5F;&#x78;&#x30;&#x30;&#x32;&#x30;&#x5F;&#x31;&#x22;&#x3E;&#x0A;&#x20;&#x20;&#x3C;&#x6D;&#x65;&#x74;&#x61;&#x64;&#x61;&#x74;&#x61;&#x20;&#x69;&#x64;&#x3D;&#x22;&#x43;&#x6F;&#x72;&#x65;&#x6C;&#x43;&#x6F;&#x72;&#x70;&#x49;&#x44;&#x5F;&#x30;&#x43;&#x6F;&#x72;&#x65;&#x6C;&#x2D;&#x4C;&#x61;&#x79;&#x65;&#x72;&#x22;&#x2F;&#x3E;&#x0A;&#x20;&#x20;&#x3C;&#x70;&#x61;&#x74;&#x68;&#x20;&#x63;&#x6C;&#x61;&#x73;&#x73;&#x3D;&#x22;&#x66;&#x69;&#x6C;&#x30;&#x22;&#x20;&#x64;&#x3D;&#x22;&#x4D;&#x35;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x34;&#x32;&#x34;&#x38;&#x20;&#x31;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x30;&#x32;&#x32;&#x33;&#x63;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x39;&#x30;&#x39;&#x31;&#x32;&#x37;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x35;&#x37;&#x30;&#x33;&#x31;&#x36;&#x20;&#x32;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x35;&#x38;&#x35;&#x36;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x39;&#x39;&#x34;&#x36;&#x35;&#x35;&#x20;&#x33;&#x2E;&#x33;&#x37;&#x32;&#x36;&#x38;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x37;&#x39;&#x35;&#x37;&#x34;&#x38;&#x20;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x34;&#x35;&#x38;&#x31;&#x34;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x33;&#x36;&#x30;&#x37;&#x34;&#x35;&#x20;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x37;&#x30;&#x37;&#x32;&#x34;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x35;&#x38;&#x34;&#x34;&#x33;&#x34;&#x20;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x31;&#x38;&#x30;&#x32;&#x38;&#x34;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x34;&#x32;&#x35;&#x37;&#x35;&#x32;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x39;&#x36;&#x39;&#x36;&#x39;&#x37;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x36;&#x38;&#x32;&#x39;&#x36;&#x36;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x31;&#x2E;&#x38;&#x39;&#x32;&#x33;&#x37;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x31;&#x36;&#x36;&#x35;&#x30;&#x38;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x32;&#x2E;&#x37;&#x31;&#x31;&#x35;&#x33;&#x2C;&#x31;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x36;&#x38;&#x32;&#x33;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x35;&#x34;&#x33;&#x33;&#x32;&#x36;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x36;&#x38;&#x31;&#x39;&#x37;&#x32;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x39;&#x33;&#x31;&#x39;&#x39;&#x39;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x31;&#x31;&#x32;&#x36;&#x35;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x31;&#x32;&#x36;&#x36;&#x32;&#x35;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x31;&#x34;&#x37;&#x32;&#x36;&#x38;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x32;&#x31;&#x33;&#x32;&#x30;&#x32;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x33;&#x32;&#x37;&#x38;&#x32;&#x38;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x34;&#x35;&#x31;&#x34;&#x37;&#x33;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x36;&#x30;&#x39;&#x36;&#x36;&#x39;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x37;&#x31;&#x34;&#x38;&#x31;&#x32;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x38;&#x34;&#x35;&#x35;&#x7A;&#x6D;&#x2D;&#x34;&#x2E;&#x38;&#x36;&#x39;&#x32;&#x38;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x37;&#x37;&#x30;&#x32;&#x33;&#x38;&#x63;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x31;&#x39;&#x31;&#x36;&#x32;&#x31;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x33;&#x32;&#x32;&#x33;&#x38;&#x36;&#x20;&#x32;&#x2E;&#x31;&#x37;&#x38;&#x35;&#x36;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x32;&#x39;&#x36;&#x32;&#x35;&#x37;&#x20;&#x32;&#x2E;&#x33;&#x31;&#x37;&#x39;&#x33;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x20;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x31;&#x37;&#x31;&#x31;&#x38;&#x38;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x35;&#x31;&#x35;&#x35;&#x33;&#x20;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x31;&#x38;&#x31;&#x36;&#x39;&#x37;&#x2C;&#x31;&#x2E;&#x31;&#x38;&#x31;&#x30;&#x37;&#x20;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x31;&#x30;&#x32;&#x30;&#x39;&#x37;&#x2C;&#x31;&#x2E;&#x39;&#x33;&#x30;&#x37;&#x33;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x31;&#x39;&#x35;&#x38;&#x32;&#x37;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x33;&#x32;&#x35;&#x30;&#x37;&#x39;&#x20;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x32;&#x30;&#x39;&#x30;&#x34;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x33;&#x33;&#x32;&#x34;&#x38;&#x36;&#x20;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x36;&#x30;&#x37;&#x34;&#x39;&#x34;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x31;&#x32;&#x32;&#x35;&#x35;&#x32;&#x20;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x31;&#x37;&#x32;&#x37;&#x37;&#x38;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x38;&#x36;&#x34;&#x36;&#x36;&#x33;&#x20;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x36;&#x31;&#x32;&#x39;&#x36;&#x39;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x33;&#x35;&#x34;&#x33;&#x33;&#x32;&#x20;&#x31;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x37;&#x36;&#x35;&#x37;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x37;&#x33;&#x31;&#x39;&#x35;&#x36;&#x20;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x31;&#x38;&#x31;&#x32;&#x32;&#x33;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x31;&#x34;&#x37;&#x36;&#x31;&#x20;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x33;&#x37;&#x37;&#x36;&#x33;&#x35;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x32;&#x39;&#x35;&#x32;&#x35;&#x33;&#x20;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x35;&#x38;&#x38;&#x31;&#x38;&#x37;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x34;&#x33;&#x36;&#x32;&#x39;&#x34;&#x20;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x32;&#x37;&#x36;&#x32;&#x32;&#x32;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x32;&#x37;&#x30;&#x32;&#x37;&#x32;&#x20;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x35;&#x31;&#x37;&#x35;&#x33;&#x39;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x35;&#x36;&#x35;&#x38;&#x31;&#x32;&#x20;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x37;&#x31;&#x38;&#x34;&#x34;&#x34;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x38;&#x39;&#x30;&#x36;&#x35;&#x39;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x38;&#x39;&#x38;&#x39;&#x39;&#x33;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x38;&#x34;&#x33;&#x36;&#x38;&#x39;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x32;&#x31;&#x36;&#x39;&#x31;&#x31;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x32;&#x33;&#x36;&#x33;&#x39;&#x34;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x35;&#x30;&#x30;&#x34;&#x32;&#x39;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x35;&#x34;&#x32;&#x37;&#x38;&#x35;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x36;&#x36;&#x34;&#x34;&#x38;&#x37;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x37;&#x31;&#x38;&#x30;&#x39;&#x31;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x32;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x35;&#x33;&#x37;&#x2C;&#x31;&#x2E;&#x35;&#x35;&#x33;&#x39;&#x39;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x33;&#x2E;&#x31;&#x34;&#x32;&#x30;&#x35;&#x2C;&#x31;&#x2E;&#x35;&#x30;&#x34;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x38;&#x30;&#x31;&#x30;&#x35;&#x38;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x33;&#x36;&#x37;&#x39;&#x32;&#x31;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x31;&#x2E;&#x35;&#x30;&#x38;&#x35;&#x35;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x32;&#x37;&#x33;&#x39;&#x38;&#x31;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x31;&#x2E;&#x37;&#x36;&#x38;&#x32;&#x35;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x31;&#x2E;&#x33;&#x33;&#x37;&#x33;&#x33;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x32;&#x36;&#x37;&#x36;&#x36;&#x37;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x31;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x39;&#x35;&#x39;&#x36;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x31;&#x39;&#x31;&#x32;&#x33;&#x35;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x31;&#x2E;&#x39;&#x31;&#x31;&#x37;&#x35;&#x20;&#x30;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x32;&#x2E;&#x34;&#x38;&#x35;&#x31;&#x35;&#x7A;&#x6D;&#x31;&#x2E;&#x31;&#x36;&#x39;&#x31;&#x31;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x31;&#x32;&#x32;&#x38;&#x33;&#x39;&#x63;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x34;&#x32;&#x38;&#x37;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x20;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x37;&#x37;&#x36;&#x33;&#x35;&#x33;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x33;&#x35;&#x30;&#x39;&#x32;&#x31;&#x20;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x37;&#x37;&#x36;&#x33;&#x35;&#x33;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x37;&#x38;&#x33;&#x37;&#x34;&#x39;&#x20;&#x30;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x34;&#x33;&#x32;&#x38;&#x32;&#x38;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x33;&#x34;&#x37;&#x36;&#x35;&#x33;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x37;&#x38;&#x33;&#x37;&#x34;&#x39;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x37;&#x37;&#x36;&#x33;&#x35;&#x33;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x37;&#x38;&#x33;&#x37;&#x34;&#x39;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x34;&#x32;&#x38;&#x36;&#x38;&#x39;&#x2C;&#x30;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x37;&#x37;&#x36;&#x33;&#x34;&#x32;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x33;&#x35;&#x30;&#x39;&#x32;&#x31;&#x20;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x37;&#x37;&#x36;&#x33;&#x34;&#x32;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x37;&#x38;&#x33;&#x37;&#x34;&#x39;&#x20;&#x30;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x34;&#x33;&#x32;&#x38;&#x32;&#x38;&#x20;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x33;&#x34;&#x37;&#x36;&#x35;&#x33;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x37;&#x38;&#x33;&#x37;&#x34;&#x39;&#x20;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x37;&#x37;&#x36;&#x33;&#x34;&#x32;&#x2C;&#x2D;&#x30;&#x2E;&#x30;&#x37;&#x38;&#x33;&#x37;&#x34;&#x39;&#x7A;&#x22;&#x2F;&#x3E;&#x0A;&#x20;&#x3C;&#x2F;&#x67;&#x3E;&#x0A;&#x3C;&#x2F;&#x67;&#x3E;&#x0D;&#x0A;&#x3C;&#x2F;&#x73;&#x76;&#x67;&#x3E;
```

Hm, close but no cigar! :D

> "Ceci n'est pas une pipe!"

However, if you view the above string in a browser you see the following:

```
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" width="100px" height="46px" style="shape-rendering:geometricPrecision; text-rendering:geometricPrecision; image-rendering:optimizeQuality; fill-rule:evenodd; clip-rule:evenodd" viewBox="0 0 8.89145 4.05659">
 <defs>
  <style type="text/css">

    .fil0 {fill:#0A0B0C}

  </style>
 </defs>
 <g id="Layer_x0020_1">
  <metadata id="CorelCorpID_0Corel-Layer"/>
  <path class="fil0" d="M5.04248 1.00223c0.909127,-0.570316 2.05856,-0.994655 3.37268,-0.795748 0.45814,-0.360745 0.70724,0.584434 0.180284,0.425752 -0.969697,-0.0682966 -1.89237,0.166508 -2.71153,1.06823 -0.0543326,0.0681972 -0.0931999,0.11265 -0.126625,0.147268 -0.213202,-0.327828 -0.451473,-0.609669 -0.714812,-0.8455zm-4.86928 -0.770238c0.191621,-0.322386 2.17856,-0.296257 2.31793,0 0.171188,0.51553 0.181697,1.18107 0.102097,1.93073 -0.0195827,0.325079 0.20904,0.332486 0.607494,0.122552 0.172778,-0.0864663 0.612969,-0.354332 1.07657,-0.731956 0.181223,-0.14761 0.377635,-0.295253 0.588187,-0.436294 0.276222,0.270272 0.517539,0.565812 0.718444,0.890659 -0.0898993,0.0843689 -0.216911,0.236394 -0.500429,0.542785 -0.664487,0.718091 -2.0537,1.55399 -3.14205,1.504 -0.801058,-0.0367921 -1.50855,-0.273981 -1.76825,-1.33733 -0.267667,-1.09596 -0.191235,-1.91175 0,-2.48515zm1.16911 -0.122839c0.4287,0 0.776353,0.0350921 0.776353,0.0783749 0,0.0432828 -0.347653,0.0783749 -0.776353,0.0783749 -0.428689,0 -0.776342,-0.0350921 -0.776342,-0.0783749 0,-0.0432828 0.347653,-0.0783749 0.776342,-0.0783749z"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

And if you copy *that* string and view it in the browser once again you get the SVG image that I am looking to extract:

[image: pipe.svg]

---

So how do you get from the HexData to the SVG XML - in a single XSLT 1.0 transformation?

Specifically:

- Is it possible in XSLT 1.0 to implement an entity-to-character transformation (that the browser performs naturally)?
- Or a hex-to-character transformation directly?
- And is it easier to set the xls:output to text instead of xml?

Comment: None of the three questions you ask are the real problem here. You are trying to convert an escaped string (payload) into marked-up text. This is possible in XSLT 3.0, using the parse-xml() function. In XSLT 1.0, your only option is to save an interim result to a file, then apply another transformation to that file.

Comment: Another good question is decode it to what? Possibly I missed that in all the above. But if all you want is to "use" that data in something like HTML img tag then just use it with data:

Comment: @michael.hor257k - yes and no. Yes, you are right that you can first use parse-xml() in XSLT 3.0, but, no,  I don't actually need to parse the XML, because I want to output the svg-xml without any further transformation. Thus

Comment: I think the main problem here, is that the (tantalizingly simple) use of entities to convert hex to characters is a dead-end, because there is no method to convert entities to characters in xml 1.0.

Comment: I am afraid your diagnosis is entirely wrong. These "entities" (more precisely: numeric character references) **are** characters. Your situation, after converting the hex stream to character data, is no different from having received the entire SVG as an escaped string or CDATA to begin with. It needs to be parsed anew, and this cannot be done in XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.